# Python Module 'shader': from shader import ShaderProgram, ShaderCode

Tags: python, pyqt, shader

I'm trying to run a python application from source, and it has:

```
from shader import ShaderProgram,ShaderCode
```

I don't know what to download + install to get 'shader'. It's pretty unspecific and can't find the answer anywhere, anyone know what module this is?

This is a python / pyqt application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the program you're looking at is [Inkspot](https://code.google.com/p/inkspot/) (and it looks like that, since it's basically the only google hit besides this question for "from shader import ShaderProgram,ShaderCode"), *shader* is another module belonging to the program, not an external dependency. See the source of shader.py [here](https://code.google.com/p/inkspot/source/browse/trunk/src/shader.py).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the application you're looking for is [PyOpenGL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyopengl/).

Comment: Hey there, doesn't seem to be pyopengl, I installed it and it still complains.